Group multiple events for ID in postgreSQL data
I'm trying to select pairs of events from my data. I have a data that looks like this:
CREATE TABLE test (id, status, created) AS VALUES
       (1, 'on',  '2024-09-01'::DATE)
     , (2, 'on',  '2024-09-02'::DATE)
     , (1, 'off', '2024-09-03'::DATE)
     , (1, 'on',  '2024-09-04'::DATE)
     , (2, 'off', '2024-09-05'::DATE)
     , (3, 'on',  '2024-09-06'::DATE)
     , (1, 'off', '2024-09-07'::DATE)
     , (4, 'off', '2024-09-08'::DATE)
     , (4, 'off', '2024-09-09'::DATE)
     , (4, 'on',  '2024-09-10'::DATE)
     , (4, 'on',  '2024-09-11'::DATE)
     , (4, 'on',  '2024-09-12'::DATE)
     , (3, 'on',  '2024-09-12'::DATE)
     , (3, 'off', '2024-09-14'::DATE)
     , (4, 'off', '2024-09-16'::DATE);

I would like to have data like this:



id
switch_on
switch_off




1
2024-09-01
2024-09-03


1
2024-09-04
2024-09-07


2
2024-09-02
2024-09-05


3
2024-09-06



3
2024-09-12
2024-09-14


4

2024-09-08


4

2024-09-09


4
2024-09-10



4
2024-09-11



4
2024-09-12
2024-09-16



I am interested in:

multiple events for the same id in the data
null values when either end of event pair is missing


You can use lag()/lead() window functions, run a scalar subquery or self-join the table.

full outer join ?

"I'm trying to select pairs of events from my data" - I don't see you trying anything. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please show your approach, so we can comment on it.

You say there can be rows missing in the table, so we sometimes don't see a matching 'on' or 'off'. The problem with this is that you can get wrong results. Where you might show on = 2024-09-04 and off = 2024-09-17, it may well be that between these two there is an 'off' and an 'on' missing and the correct result might be something like two two-days ranges 2024-09-04 to 2024-09-05 and 2024-09-16 to 2024-09-17 rather than one fourteen-day range of 2024-09-04 to 2024-09-17.

This is no easy task. What I do below is to build groups of up to two rows using the internal row ID called CTID in PostgreSQL. All rows use their own CTID for a group key, except for 'off' rows following immediately an 'on' row. These get the 'on' rows' CTIDs instead, thus coupling with them.
In the next step I aggregate by those group keys showing the switch_on and switch_off values. At last PostgreSQL forces me to wrap this again in a select, because it is unable to apply COALESCE on the selected alias names, which I consider a bug.
select *
from
(
  select
    id,
    min(created) filter (where status = 'on') as switch_on,
    min(created) filter (where status = 'off') as switch_off
  from
  (
    select 
      id,
      status,
      created,
      case when status = 'off' and lag(status) over w = 'on'
        then lag(ctid) over w
        else ctid
        end as grp
    from test
    window w as (partition by id order by created, status desc)
  ) grouped
  group by grp, id
) result
order by id, coalesce(switch_on, switch_off);

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/KqJoUw_O

+1 Not only does this handle strange repetitions of status in a way more reasonable manner than the currently accepted answer, it also does that much faster and more efficiently.

An example using the self-join:

Match on id
Make sure the left table is for earlier on events, right for later off.
This matches every on event with all later offs for each id. A distinct on keeps only a single match for each id and on event, selecting the soonest off.

demo at db<>fiddle
select distinct on (1,2)
       coalesce(t1.id,t2.id)
      ,t1.created as switched_on 
      ,t2.created as switched_off
from test as t1 
full join test as t2 
       on t1.id=t2.id 
      and t1.created<t2.created
      and t1.status='on'
      and t2.status='off'
where coalesce(t1.status,'on')='on' 
  and coalesce(t2.status,'off')='off'
order by 1,2, t2.created-t1.created;




coalesce
switched_on
switched_off




1
2024-09-01
2024-09-03


1
2024-09-04
2024-09-07


2
2024-09-02
2024-09-05


3
2024-09-06
null


4
null
2024-09-08




one more solution https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h8ybfLgXfmVNE32UZ9PjKc/0

one more solution: https://dbfiddle.uk/zFD4Qacf

Why provide solutions as comment and not as answer?

@mrmcwolf That's returning 7% over the number of expected results, Luuk's returns 0.0001% too few. Take a look at the row counts in this test.

@Zegarek: Can you explain where I can find this 0.0001% in eleven records?

I think the task is a tad more complicated. As there can obviously be 'on' and 'off' rows missing, we cannot assume that a missing 'off' row is the last in line for an ID or that there is always only just one row missing for an ID. See https://dbfiddle.uk/MybPi1SJ

@Luuk I mean the example above returns 46'591 rows given the 100'008 random sample set, while the example from the fiddle you posted returns 46'981. The data is random, so I don't know what tripped it specifically, but if you manage to track it down, I'd be interested to take a look. It might also be the case that it's my code that's wrong and I'm getting 10 too many.

@Zegarek, It cannot return any more records. This is a full join and it returns all on and all off (no more, no less). Of course, it is possible to return the wrong data because it relies on date sorting to associate first on with first off, regardless of the date. This can be fixed, but it's pointless. It is better to improve the structure of the database to exclude the possibility of such behavior.

@ThorstenKettner You're right. While this does handle the leading off reasonably, any repeated statuses result in overlapping ranges that I don't think should be considered valid. One idea would be to slap yet another distinct on to pick the widest range, but I guess it's better to wait for OP to clarify their rules.

on my test I do return 0.008532 % more records than your query, a quick (on only a quick test!) revealed missing records on your query.

I think it would be much easier to discuss the other solutions if you posted them as answers. Then we could leave this comment section for discussion on this one, and move the tests and remarks on the other solutions to their corresponding comment sections. @Luuk It would be great if you could share a db<>fiddle with the test, even better if it was in a separately posted answer.

@Zegarek: Because of the random data a screenshot https://i.sstatic.net/MBsgChep.png, and the fiddle used to create it: https://dbfiddle.uk/jR3cNwwe.  Maya I wish you luck on debugging this...

@Luuk Done, thanks. The random sample generation in my fiddles was stabilised using setseed() but it turns out I didn't fully resolve ties between samples generated for the same date and id, so those kept spawning randomly in a way setseed() doesn't affect. Fixed that, checked a few diffs and found I forgot the on/off statuses should've been both in the join as well as the where conditions, and I only had them in one of these. Big thanks for helping track this down. Here's the comparison fiddle, with the fix.
